# How does one create a custom 403 page in Django?

Tags: django, http-status-code-403

Following this documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views), I am trying to create a custom error 403 page for my Django application.

I have created an error handler in my URLConf:

```
handler403 = 'courses.views.error403'
```

I have also created a view that handles error 403 called error403:

```
def error403(request):
    '''
    Default view for error 403: Inadequate permissions.
    '''
    return render_to_response('utility/mustLogin.html', {'user': request.user})
```

However, this view is simply not rendering. When I instigate an error 403 on purpose, the default browser 403 page merely appears as opposed to my template.

[image: Default browser 403]

Am I forgetting to perform some action? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `handler403` is new in the development version. If you're using an older version (<= 1.3) this option is not yet implemented.

There are some ways of accomplishing that in older versions, as described [here](http://theglenbot.com/creating-a-custom-http403-exception-in-django/). It involves a new middleware, a custom exception and the [HttpResponseForbidden](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseForbidden). Don't know how well it would integrate with the rest of your project, though...

Comment: Ah, I am using 1.2.3. That would make sense.

Comment: I think you can instead configure a custom one, with apache, nginx or similar if you're using one of those web servers, as an alternative.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is in Django 1.4 or later

Answer (score 4):

Google Chrome will replace it with their generic one if the returned page is less than 512 bytes in size. They do the same with 404 responses as well.

For what it's worth Internet Explorer does the same thing.

If you make your response greater than 512bytes then all shall be well.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that. Nonetheless, the template is still not rendering after I made my page >512 bytes (I filled the page with over 512 digits in a <p> tag - one char is a byte right?).

Comment: See mgibsonbr response below, what version of django are you running?